# Right of return for already replaced goods

Tags: business, consumer-protection

Around 9 months ago I purchased a product, a pair of headphones, in the UK directly from the manufacturer. After 5 months, this product became defective, and was exchanged for another identical product. Upon exchange, I was provided with a new order number and confirmation email for the new product. Now, another 4 months later, the new replacement product has developed another defect, and I'd like to return it again.

I have read that, per the Sale of Goods Act 1979, I should be able to get the goods replaced if it was less than 6 months from when I purchased them, but, legally, is the date of purchase for the replaced product 9 months ago when I made the initial purchase, or 4 months ago when I received another order confirmation for the brand new replacement goods? I'm inclined to believe that the date of purchase would be the date on which I paid for the goods, but then the second order confirmation from 4 months ago makes me wonder if I might have a case.

Either way, I'm aware that a £60 pair of headphones won't be a major loss, but after hours of frustration with customer support I'm genuinely interested to know just what my rights are here!

Thanks in anticipation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wait until 1 October 2015 the Consumer Rights Act 2015 will come into force; I have had a brief look at the regulation and it appears that it will cover contracts that are "on hand" when it does.

Under that your rights are very clear: you are entitled to a replacement, if the replacement becomes defective you are entitled to another replacement or a refund at your discretion.